# Como agregar propiedades a un objeto

Tags: javascript

Tengo que juntar dos variables en un objeto, la primer variable ya es un objeto y la segunda es un arreglo de objetos del estilo:

```
[{"$":{"CODIGO":"CODIGOAMBIENTEDEFAULT","RESPOSTA":"TSL"}}, {"$":{"CODIGO":"CODIGOARTICULO","RESPOSTA":"INXXMADHRJFIJTAR8MMXXXXXXXXXXXXX040_010_010"}}]
```

Yo quiero utilizar el contenido de la variable `CODIGO` como propiedad y el contenido de la variable `REPOSTA` como dato, es decir que en el primer ítem del arreglo debería quedar:

```
{"CODIGOAMBIENTEDEFAULT":"TSL"}
```

Ahora bien, yo lo que hago es:

```
function buscaDatos(item)
{
    var variables = {};

    for(var x in item.$)
    {
        variables[x] = item.$[x];
    }

    for(var i = 0; i < (item.hasOwnProperty('CONFIGURADO'))?item.CONFIGURADO[0].CARACTERISTICA.length:0; i++)
    {
        variables[item.CONFIGURADO[0].CARACTERISTICA[i].$.CODIGO] = item.CONFIGURADO[0].CARACTERISTICA[i].$.RESPOSTA;
    }
    return {"$":item.$, "CONFIGURADO":item.CONFIGURADO, "item":variables};
}
```

Pero cuando hago esto el objeto variables contiene todas las propiedades del objeto `item.&` pero sólo el primer ítem del arreglo ignorando los otros 43 items.

¿Qué estoy haciendo mal?

Comment: Si no entiendo mal, quieres que la clave de tu nuevo objeto sea el valor de `CODIGO` y el valor sea el de `RESPOSTA` ?

Comment: Exacto, eso es lo que quiero.

Answer (score 3):

Una forma de hacerlo es usando `map()` y sería algo así si entendí bien cual es el resultado esperado

```js
const arr = [{"$":{"CODIGO":"CODIGOAMBIENTEDEFAULT","RESPOSTA":"TSL"}}, {"$":{"CODIGO":"CODIGOARTICULO","RESPOSTA":"INXXMADHRJFIJTAR8MMXXXXXXXXXXXXX040_010_010"}}];


const res = arr.map(e=>{e[e["$"].CODIGO] = e["$"].RESPOSTA; delete e['$']; return e;});


console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 2):

Gracias a los comentarios, la solución que llegué fue la siguiente:

```
function buscaDatos(item)
{
    var variables = {};

    for(var x in item.$)
    {
        variables[x] = item.$[x];
    }

    var temp = (item.hasOwnProperty('CONFIGURADO'))?item.CONFIGURADO[0].CARACTERISTICA:[];

    for(var i = 0; i < temp.length; i++)
    {
        variables[temp[i].$.CODIGO] = temp[i].$.RESPOSTA;
    }

    return {"$":item.$, "CONFIGURADO":item.CONFIGURADO, "item":variables};
}
```

La única diferencia es que para manejar el arreglo lo guardo en una variable y listo.

De todas formas me sigo preguntando porqué no funcionaba de la primer forma.

Gracias a todos!

Answer (score 1):

Una forma de hacerlo es crear un nuevo objeto y agregarles dinámicamente la propiedad con su valor:

```js
let arr = [{"$":{"CODIGO":"CODIGOAMBIENTEDEFAULT","RESPOSTA":"TSL"}}, {"$":{"CODIGO":"CODIGOARTICULO","RESPOSTA":"INXXMADHRJFIJTAR8MMXXXXXXXXXXXXX040_010_010"}}];

let arrNuevo = [];
for(let item of arr) {
  let itemNuevo = {};
  itemNuevo[item['$']['CODIGO']] = item['$']['RESPOSTA'];
  arrNuevo[arrNuevo.length] = itemNuevo;

}

for(let i=0; i<arrNuevo.length; i++){
  console.log(arrNuevo[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Las respuestas anteriores son resueltas mediante programación estructurada, excepto Emeeus, haciendo uso extensivo de infraestructura que satura el código. 
mi solución utiliza bibliotecas ya existentes que pueden apoyarte para no dejar un código que requiera tiempo para entenderse.

```
import _ from "underscore"

const _data = [{"$":{"CODIGO":"CODIGOAMBIENTEDEFAULT","RESPOSTA":"TSL"}}, {"$":{"CODIGO":"CODIGOARTICULO","RESPOSTA":"INXXMADHRJFIJTAR8MMXXXXXXXXXXXXX040_010_010"}}]

function result  (datos) {
   return _.map(datos,x=> makeObject(x));
};
function makeObject (x) {
   var obj={};
   obj[x.$.CODIGO] = x.$.RESPOSTA;
return obj;
};
console.log(result(_data));
```

por supuesto, la función makeObject puede quedar dentro de la línea del map, pero la saqué para clarificar.

La respuesta a tu pregunta está en la parte de js que permite ampliar los objetos a libre voluntad, en la línea

```
var obj={};
obj[x.$.CODIGO] = x.$.RESPOSTA;
```

es decir que a cualquier objeto puedes agregarle una propiedad simplemente asignándola.