# Como convertir un array anidado en un array de objetos en javascript

Tags: javascript

```
[[1, "name", "value"],[2, "name2", "value2"],[3, "name3", "value3"]]
```

y lo quiero convertir a un arreglo de objetos.

```
[{1, "name", "value"},{2, "name2", "value2"},{3, "name3", "value3"}]
```

---

```
let someArray = [
  ["id", "name", "age"],
  [1, "name", "value" ],
  [2, "name1", "value1"],
  [3, "name2", "value2"] ];
function toObject(arr){

  let array=[]

  for(let i=1; i<arr.length; i++){
   const returned=Object.assign({},arr[i])
    array.push(returned);
  }
  return array
 }
console.log(toObject(someArray));
```

He creado esta función pero no se si haya una mejor forma de resolverlo.

Comment: En `Javascript` para poder asignar un valor a un objeto, debes declarar una propiedad y a esta asignarle el valor. Teniendo esto presente, el resultado que deseas obtener es imposible de alcanzar. **Nota**: la sintaxis no es válida.

Answer (score 1):

Como @Marcos menciona este tipo de 'objeto' que pides para el resultado es incorrecto en javascript, pero...
Para operaciones con arreglos y listas en js usa la biblioteca de Underscoreljs, que tiene una función map. descárgala en [https://underscorejs.org/](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/285781/como-agregar-propiedades-a-un-objeto/285968#285968)

Con esa te facilitas el código, ya que no requerirás modelar infraestructura tipo for{}

el ejemplo lo encuentras en 
[este link de Stack Overflow](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/285781/como-agregar-propiedades-a-un-objeto/285968#285968)

y es muy parecido a este que hice:

```
const _data2 = [[1, "name", "value"],[2, "name2", "value2"],[3, "name3", "value3"]];

function result2  (datos) {
  return _.map(datos, (x)=>{
    const primer = x[0];
    const segundo = x[1];
    const tercero = x[2];
    var obj={primer, segundo, tercero};
    return obj;
  } )
};
console.log(result2(_data2));
```

Revisa este link:
[Objetos en javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Trabajando_con_objectos)

Dado que la solución es incorrecta, al parecer la pregunta es incorrecta. Yo considero que lo que tratas de hacer es lo que hago en el primer ejemplo (link), ya sea un arreglo de objetos {valor, propiedad} o un solo objeto {varlor1:propiedad1, valor2:propiedad2...}
En cualquiera de estos últimos casos deberás formular otra pregunta...

Comment: No es necesario usar una librería externa para implementar [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/map). Por otro lado, el formato que plantea el OP no es un formato `json` válido. No entiendo a qué te refieres cuando dices: *este tipo de 'objeto' es algo raro para javascript*. ¿Cuál es el tipo de objeto *algo raro*? Saludos

Comment: @MauricioContreras Tienes razón, edito para que quede claro que lo que pide como resultado no es un objeto correcto en javascript.